# Add existing PDF literally

Tags: pdf, graphics, include

I am new on LaTeX and I am struggling to take a pdf and just use it as is.

I need the pages of a PDF to be placed there, no includegraphics or similars.

Just take the 2 pages of the PDF and place them there, they are the title pages of a document I need to write and I want to use them, not *add* them.

Is this possible ? Without adding, trimming etc.

Hope it's clear, thank you.

Comment: So you have an *existing* document that you want to grab two pages from *another* document and insert them as-is? Do you have anything else in your existing document?

Comment: @Werner I have 1 PDF (A) and then the LaTeX generated PDF (B). I want to take A and put it in the beginning of B. Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding PDF pages *as-is* to an existing LaTeX document is easily achieved via [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). In your preamble add

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

and wherever you want to include the PDF, add

```
\includepdf[<opts>]{<file>}
```

in your document. To include the entire `<file>`, use `pages=-` in your `<opts>`, or specify the pages.